# Trying to find a Shopify Email Variable for Order URL

Tags: e-commerce, shopify

I find it strange this isn't offered but I'm looking to get the URL to specific orders (store.com/account/orders/customstring) passed through an email template variable.

Consulting the Shopify docs here: https://help.shopify.com/manual/sell-online/notifications/email-variables, I don't see how I can achieve that. Wondering if anyone has any idea on how to do it, if possible?

Something like {{order.url}} or account/orders/{{order.hash}}  << *(obviously made those up)*

Comment: Does `{{ order_status_url }}` not work for you? This redirects you to a page with most of the information entered in the checkout process + the products in that order.

Comment: Yeah but I need it to specifically go to the order page in their account... not the order confirmation page at the end of checkout.

It's strange - Shopify offers it as a link for shop owners (e.g. admin/orders/order_id) for use in the New Order email template but not on the consumer facing side of things.

Comment: This is so because a customer, unlike the admin, is entitled to only his/her order details. This is the main reason why consumer side order details are inside the customer object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopped on Shopify support and they confirmed there's no way to do it. Close this question as it's no longer relevant :(